# TFTP packet example?

Tags: ruby, tftp

I'm writing a TFTP server in Ruby and I don't understand a couple things.

First, I read through [the entire RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1350.txt) and I understand the TFTP part of the packet (2 bytes opcode, etc), but I don't know where the TID's go. Also, I've never done anything in Ruby at a byte level. I don't know how to create a variable that's 2 bytes this and then 1 byte that and then whatever.

If someone could show me an example of how to construct a read request packet in ruby, that'd be sweet. Say I'm on the client side and I select port #20000 (for my local TID) and I want to read the file named `/Users/pachun/documents/hello.txt` on the server which has a TID of 69 right now because it's the first request. How would I construct that packet in Ruby?

Comment: Can you tell us what that packet would look like in binary so we don't have to read the whole RFC?

Comment: Search for "Order of Headers" on in the RFC and it should be in I. Appendix. It describes the packet layout. EDIT: it's the second occurance of "Order of Headers" in the RFC.

Comment: The first thing to do is show code you've been working on. It's always easier for us to correct your code than to write something from scratch; Our code might not fit your codebase at all and could require a lot of rework on your part, or worse, be unusable.

Comment: "[ruby tftp server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038283/ruby-tftp-server)" might help, along with the source code for "[putbinary(remotefile, io)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/net-tftp-0.1.0/Net/TFTP.html#method-i-putbinary)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this project:

https://github.com/spiceworks/net-tftp

The code there should answer your questions regarding how to construct byte sequences for communicating with tftp protocol.